# What is the difference between LinkedList and ArrayList, and when to use which one?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`? How do I know when to use which one?

Comment: Simple for ArrayList, never. Use the generic collections `IList<T>` and related.

Answer (score 13):

The difference is the internal data structure used to store the objects.

An `ArrayList` will use a system array (like `Object[]`) and resize it when needed. On the other hand, a `LinkedList` will use an object that contains the data and a pointer to the next and previous objects in the list.

Different operations will have different algorithmic complexity due to this difference in the internal representation.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use either. Use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

That really is my recommendation. Probably independently of what your application is, but here's a little more color just in case you're doing something that needs a finely tuned choice here.

`ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are different implementations of the storage mechanism for a `List`. `ArrayList` uses an array that it must resize if your collection outgrows it current storage size. `LinkedList` on the other hand uses the linked list data structure from CS 201. `LinkedList` is better for some head- or tail-insert heavy workloads, but `ArrayList` is better for random access workloads.

Comment: Why would you recommend to always use an array-based list when he explicitly asked when each (array v. link) is best?

Comment: My point is that you don't usually have to agonize over choice here. There are tons of places in the base class libraries where you get a List back regardless of whether that's what you wish you got or not. (`*.ToList()`) `LinkedList` doesn't even implement `IList`, so it can't be automatically used in lots of `List` contexts.

If you need to use a `LinkedList` for performance reasons, that's completely fine, but on average you're losing more than you gain.

Comment: No one said you should agonize.  It's usually a relatively simple decision.  I don't understand why you think you must use `List` just because certain parts of the standard library do.  `LinkedList` deliberately doesn't implement `IList` to minimize people misusing it.  Even it were true that "on average you're losing", the OP didn't ask about average.  He asked about *when* to use each.

Comment: And I discussed _when_ to use each. I apologize for writing a short answer before the full discussion?

Answer (score 9):

**`ArrayList`** has a good replacement which is `List<T>`.

In general, **`List<T>`** is a wrapper for array - it allows indexing and accessing items in *O(1)*, but, every time you exceed the capacity an *O(n)* must be paid.

**`LinkedList<T>`** won't let you access items using index but you can count that insert will always cost *O(1)*. In addition, you can insert items in to the beginning of the list and between existing items in *O(1)*.

I think that in most cases `List<T>` is the default choice. Many of the common scenarios don't require special order and have no strict complexity constraints, therefore `List<T>` is preferred due to its usage simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between `ArrayList` and `List<T>`, `LinkedList<T>`, and other similar Generics is that `ArrayList` holds `Object`s, while the others hold a type that you specify (ie. `List<Point>` holds only Points).

Because of this, you need to cast any object you take out of an `ArrayList` to its actual type.  This can take a lot of screen space if you have long class names.

In general it's much better to use `List<T>` and other typed Generics unless you really need to have a list with multiple different types of objects in it.

Answer (score 4):

The difference lies in the semantics of how the `List` interface* is implemented:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arraylist and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedList

---

*Meaning the [basic list operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28computing%29#Operations)

Comment: You can check the algorithmic complexity of each operation on these wikipedia articles.

Comment: The interface is `IList<T>`, but `LinkedList<T>` doesn't implement it (probably deliberately, to discourage poor algorithms).

Comment: `List<T>` is not an interface, and neither `ArrayList` nor `LinkedList<T>` implement `IList<T>`.

Comment: I wasn't really going for a language-dependent answer, because (though he may be writing code in C#) the OP's question is applicable outside of C#.

Comment: Bears, the problem is that `List<T>` is a concrete type in C#, and `LinkedList<T>` doesn't even implement `IList<T>`.  So your answer is confusing.

Comment: Sorry. I guess it would have been more clear to stick with calling it something really abstract, like a `List`. I'll change that.

Answer (score 3):

As @sblom has stated, use the generic counterparts of LinkedList and ArrayList. There's really no reason not to, and plenty of reasons to do so.

The List<T> implementation is effectively wrapping an Array. Should the user attempt to insert elements beyond the bounds of the backing array, it will be copied to a larger array (at considerable expense, buit transparently to users of the List<T>)

A LinkedList<T> has a completely different implementation in which data is held in LinkedListNode<T> instances, which carry reference to two other LinkedListNode<T> instances (or only one in the case of the head or tail of the list). No external reference to mid-list items is created. This means that iterating the list is fast, but random-access is slow, because one must iterate the nodes from one end or the other. The best reason to use a LinkedList is to allow for fast inserts, that involve simply changing the references held by the nodes, rather than rewriting the entire list to insert an item (as is the case with List<T>)

Answer (score 2):

They have different performance on "inserts" (adding new elements) and lookups. For inserts ArrayLists keeps an array internally (initially 16 items long) and when you reach the max capacity it doubles the size of the array. An LinkedList starts empty and add an item (node) when needed.

I think also that with ArrayList you are able to index the items, while with the LinkedList you have to "visit" the item from the head (or the LinkedList does this automatically for you).

Comment: LinkedList also has O(1) deletes, while `List<T>` and `ArrayList` are O(n) on average (a copy is required unless the delete is at the tail).